# How to access Windows Subsystem for Linux files from Explorer.exe?

Tags: file, ubuntu, networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to access, using explorer.exe, the file structure/any file I've made using the WSL terminal, but any guide I've found online leads to a dead end.

If I use:

```
explorer.exe .
```

The explorer window opens to system32, where I can't see any wsl/linux/ubuntu related files. If use `explorer.exe [any file name]` it opens to my windows documents folder with nothing related to wsl.

Any tutorial I've found says that `explorer.exe .` should just open to the root location, but system32 isn't that. I also can't got to `\\wsl$` in the file explorer, which is recommended by a couple of guides, but that results in a network error from windows.

I can see the WSL desktop name in my network tab in explorer, but can't see any file structure, and all it says it "this folder is empty" with no options to create new files or anything.

Please help!

An edit to clarify:

When in root (username@desktop:~$), when i run `explorer.exe .` it opens the system32 folder of my windows installation. When i search in there for linux, wsl, anything like that, the only things that come up are exe files or config files. No folders.

FINAL EDIT:

This issue is fixed by updating windows to anything after the 1903 version of windows 10. After doing that, using `explorer.exe .` works perfectly.

Comment: I see more persons with the same problem. Maybe https://superuser.com/q/1338991/1083266 helps.

Comment: This issue was fixed by updating windows to anything after the 1903 version, where MS added the feature to wsl. After doing that, using "explorer.exe ." worked as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is fixed by updating windows to anything after the 1903 version of windows 10. After doing so, using `explorer.exe .` works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear as to what you are asking but if you are in the WSL bash shell and run the command `cmd.exe /c start .` you should see file explorer open in the dir you are in.

```
damo@laptop:/mnt/c/Windows/System32$ pwd
/mnt/c/Windows/System32    
damo@laptop:/mnt/c/Windows/System32$ cmd.exe /c start .
  <opens file explorer in c:\Windows\System32>
damo@laptop:/mnt/c/Windows/System32$ cd ~
damo@laptop:~$ pwd
/home/damo
damo@laptop:~$ cmd.exe /c start .
  <opens file explorer in c:\Windows\System32>
damo@laptop:~$ cd /mnt/c/stuff
damo@laptop:~$ cmd.exe /c start .
  <opens file explorer in c:\stuff>
```

Run the following to create an alias `alias start='cmd.exe /c start` which would allow you to simply run `start .` from any directory.

If you are asking how you view the linux directory structure in windows, the recommendation is "don't", you should not mess with linux files from within windows it will corrupt the wsl installation. I guess when you are in `/home/user/` and run `start .` wsl is stopping you (protecting you) for your own good by not letting you into the linux files.

hope this helps, let me know.

Comment: So I fixed this by updating windows, which is a tad annoying, but viewing/editing wsl files through explorer is now a 'feature' offered by windows, not a thing that's discouraged. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Are you using wsl2?